# Allow remote users to shut down Raspbian jessie

Tags: raspbian

How can normal users (users without sudo permissions) shutdown the system remotely?

Comment: Is the user `pi` not per default in the sudoers list on raspian, thus `sudo shutdown -h` should work?

Comment: @Ghanima yes, but this question is about non privileged users.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `policykit` (make sure `policykit-1` is installed).

Create as root `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/all_all_users_to_shutdown_reboot.pkla` with the following content:

```
[Allow all users to shutdown and reboot]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

The advantage of this method is, that you can disallow a user to shutdown, if others are logged in (omit the `*power-off-multiple-session`).

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do it is to add a line to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Make sure you use `visudo` as root to edit the file.
They will need to be on the box (`ssh`) to be able to run the shutdown command.